# Why nmap password scanner completes in 10 seconds and doesn't give any result?

Tags: passwords, nmap, network-scanners

I'm completely new to nmap and I'm trying to brute force passwords on a target. A command that I'm trying is:

```
nmap -p 80 --unprivileged --script http-form-brute <target>
```

But instead of "scanning" it ends in about 10-15 seconds with a result:

```
Host is up (0.100s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE

80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.65 seconds
```

Is it the correct result? How all the scanning could complete in such a short amount of time? Why it didn't bringed any results if a password was found or not?

**EDIT:**

After entering -v to my command, an output is:

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-24 21:30 FLE Standard Time
NSE: Loaded 1 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 21:30
Completed NSE at 21:30, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Ping Scan at 21:30
Scanning <target> [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 21:30, 0.11s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 21:30
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 21:30, 0.28s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 21:30
Scanning <target> [1 port]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on <target>
Completed Connect Scan at 21:30, 0.09s elapsed (1 total ports)
NSE: Script scanning <target>.
Initiating NSE at 21:30
Completed NSE at 21:30, 0.39s elapsed
Nmap scan report for <target>
Host is up (0.11s latency).
rDNS record for <target>

PORT   STATE SERVICE

80/tcp open  http

NSE: Script Post-scanning.

Initiating NSE at 21:30

Completed NSE at 21:30, 0.00s elapsed

Read data files from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.58 seconds
```

Comment: Please also read the documentation to know what the expected behaviour is: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-form-brute.html

Comment: I red the documentation before asking a question. But the expected result in a documentation doesn't match with mine, that's why I asked it here.

Comment: "Is it the correct result?" - the documentation shows you what the correct result looks like

Comment: The script is not running. Try adding another `-vv` to see if there are more messages to see around `NSE: Script Post-scanning.`

Comment: are there data files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap`?

Comment: Yes, as @schroeder pointed out it appears the script isn't running. My suggestion would be to try an alternative brute force method for HTTP forms, e.g. [hydra](https://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/hydra). If this works, then it can at least help you narrow down that this is an issue specific to `nmap` or your usage of it

Comment: We also don't know the specific path your form lives on, but in the [script docs](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-form-brute.html) it says that the default path argument `http-form-brute.path` is set to `/` rather than something like `/login`, for what it's worth

Comment: Most NSE scripts print debugging information when you provide the `-d` option. In the case of `http-form-brute`, this will show if it was able to detect the form on the page, what the form submission path and method was, and several other useful steps along the way.